# JFX ComboBox prompt text

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I am using Jfoenix and one thing is bothering me. As long as I didn't press the JFX ComboBox, the prompt text is shown in the JFX ComboBox. Is it possible to put it immediately above the combobox in the same way as it is after you clicked on the box?

**JFX combobox not clicked:**

[image]

**JFX combobox clicked:**

[image]

Comment: Wouldn’t it be easier to just make a Label and forego the prompt text altogether?  Labels also allow keyboard navigation, which long-time users tend to appreciate.

Comment: but there are only 3 different types to pick out so I thought it would be easier with a combobox

Comment: A ComboBox is a good control for a finite set of choices.  But your second picture could be how it always looks if you just avoid using prompt text at all.  Many applications do it that way.  Nearly all, in fact.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of "fixed" this issue by programmatically requesting focus for the combo box. After you selected the default item in your code (in my example is the first one)

```
 comboSpecies
            .getSelectionModel()
            .selectFirst();
```

Request focus by wrapping the requestFocus call in Platform.runLater

```
Platform.runLater(comboSpecies::requestFocus);
```